# Convert String To Short Form VBScript

Tags: vbscript

While you are working with files you can extract short name of a file by File.ShortName.
For example if the name is "Target.txt" then File.shortname will return "5A~.txt".

Is there any way to do this with other strings too? For example giving "Target" returns "5A~".
Possible?

Comment: What language are you trying to do this in?

Comment: what do you mean? I'm using VBScript

Comment: That's what I mean, there was no mention of VB Script in your question.

Comment: I see that now, your also tagged windows which probably shouldn't be there.

Comment: Maybe you should read [how windows generates 8.3 file names from long file names](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142982)

Comment: Yes But It can not help me a lot, because my file names' are Unicode! You can see Number and English Letters in short name as long as there is none of them in real file name! so conversion by my own hand will need lots of researches !!!

Comment: Sorry, i didn't make it clear. There is not a direct univocal translation from the source file name to the short string. It depends on the file name, but it also depends on the number of files in the folder with the same prefix. Also you should remember that short names are not always available, as its generation can be disabled.

Comment: Please Submit your comment as answer ;) I want to accept it...

Comment: You could temporarily make the file to get what its short name could be. All the above caveats would still apply. Making new files could result in the same short names